# Embed Street-View in android application

Tags: android, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I want to understand the possibilities for embedding streetview in Android application.
For better understanding, I am pasting a screenshot.
Does it require flash player, if yes, is it possible to implement?[image]

I am able to use WebView of Android to show the map and the directions, but not able to show the street view on the top widget.
Kindly help me to understand the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can implement flash player first check whether flash player is installed in your device or not by using flash package name

```
    boolean status = false;

    try {
        PackageManager pm = FreeScrollView.mContext.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.adobe.flashplayer", 0);
        if (ai != null)
            status = true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
                     status=false;
    }
```

if flash player is not installed please download flash player by using this link and then try again (http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html)